# Getting SSID and other information of a wireless network in Java

Tags: java, wifi, ssid

I'm trying to get the SSID of my wireless network device in Java. I tried the official network tutorials http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/nifs/retrieving.html but getDisplayName() getName() don't return SSID. Is there a way to get an exact SSID? Also, I'm also trying to read the wifi signal strength of all my network devices and couldn't find a way to do it. Can anyone please direct me from where to get all these information (tutorials, code samples etc)?

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done using pure Java. The Java API can take you as low as the [NetworkInterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) level in the networking stack, but not lower. When connected to a WiFi network, all SSID, handshaking and security stuff is done in lower levels than that - namely, your platform-dependent driver. The Java API (as of Java7) doesn't let you any closer to this information; you will have to use some platform-dependent code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this [jWlanScan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwlanscan/)

Comment: Yes! But it seems platform dependent. It also uses a dll extension. I'm looking for something that is totally java (no any Windows specific dlls)

Comment: 64-bit users may get the following error: "Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform" when trying to use the library.

Answer (score 0):

This is code sample where current connected wireless SSID is returned from cmd

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "netsh wlan show interfaces");    
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();

BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while (true) {
    line = r.readLine();
    if (line.contains("SSID")){
        // do something
    }
}
```