# Get SSID/ other network information in golang

Tags: networking, go, wifi, ssid

How can I get the SSID and other network information in golang?

For example the network to which I am currently connected.

Answer (score 3):

There does not seem to be a native Go command to do this. You might instead execute system-specific tools from within your Go code and check their output. Examples are

https://github.com/yelinaung/wifi-name (Linux and OS X)

or

[List of available wireless networks with golang (under Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427250/list-of-available-wireless-networks-with-golang-under-linux)

or

https://github.com/skycoin/skycoin/tree/master/src/aether/wifi (Linux)

This seems to be the same for Java:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12785503/1370397